# Which Database engine for large dataset

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, relational-database, wide-column-store

I'm working on a analysis assignment, we got a partial data-set from the university Library containing almost 300.000.000 rows.

Each row contains:

- ID
- Date
- Owner
- Deadline
- Checkout_date
- Checkin_date

I put all this inside a MySQL table, then I started querying that for my analysis assignment, however simple query (`SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = something`) where taking 9-10 minutes to complete. So I created an index for all the columns, which made it noticeable faster ~ 30 sec.

So I started reading similar issues, and people recommended switching to a "Wide column store" or "Search engine" instead of "Relational".

So my question is, what would be the best database engine to use for this data?

Comment: Please when asking this sort of question, run `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable` and include the output. This is the most clear way to showing us what indexes you have created. Also analyze your query with `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ID = 1234 \G` and include the output, that shows us how the optimizer plans to use your indexes.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, of course, "it depends".  In your example, you're counting the number of records in the database with a given ID.  I find it hard to believe that it would take 30 seconds in MySQL, unless you're on some sluggish laptop.

MySQL has powered an incredible number of systems because it is full-featured, stable, and has pretty good performance.  It's bad (or has been bad) at some things, like text search, clustering, etc.

Systems like Elasticsearch are good with globs of text, but still may not be a good fit for your system, depending on usage.  From your schema, you have one text field ("owner"), and you wouldn't need Elasticsearch's text searching capabilities on a field like that (who ever needed to stem a user name?).  Elasticsearch is also used widely for log files, which also don't need a text engine.  It is, however, good with blocks of text and with with clustering.

If this is a class assignment, I'd stick with MySQL.

Comment: However, it is not trivial to tune MySQL to handle 300 Mio rows in an optimal way, while for ES it's peanuts. The proof is there with the timings the OP gives. It's very easy to install ES, create an index and compare the timings.

Answer (score -1):

Using a search engine to search is IMO the best option.

Elasticsearch of course!

It's built to hold whatever type of data, text, numerics, geopoints, shapes and it's built for search and computation. It can easily scale out anytime you need to ingest even more data.

On a previous project (in 2011), I have been able to transform batches which were running for hours during the night to real time insights...

It's very common to see Elasticsearch clusters with some gb or pb of data nowadays...

Disclaimer: I work at elastic. :)

Comment: I'm afraid I have to downvote your answer. It includes no information on *why* Elastic is better for the OP's use case, or *how* the OP would use it to gain any advantage. Also the recommendation seem biased and self-serving, not supported by objective reasons, since you work for Elastic. I think Elastic is a great product, and I have nothing against it. But no technology is magic. It has appropriate uses, but also other cases where it offers no advantage.

Comment: I think I just answered the question "So my question is, what would be the best Database engine to use for this data?". He tagged his question with `elasticsearch` and that's the only reason I came here. Indeed. I did not answer to the question he did not ask: "and why?"...

Comment: you added no explanation and what you just wrote wasn't necessary without more context.